# how to unset array value of class member variable in php dynamically

Tags: php

I want to unset first value of member array variable of a class but I'm not able to:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public  function fun()
    {       
        $this->arr[0] = "hello";
    }

    public $arr;
}


$a = new A();
$a->fun();
$var ="arr";

unset($a->$var[0]);  //does not unset "hello" value

print_r($a);
```

I could not find any solution after searching in Google. How can I remove the first value dynamically?

Comment: `$a` is an object, use `var_dump($a)` and `$var[0]` will give you `a`. What exactly do you want to delete ?

Comment: For further problems with numerically indexed arrays and unset please have a look at my answer below, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
unset($a->{$var}[0]);
```

The problem with your code is, PHP tries to access the member variable `$var[0]` (which is `null`) and not `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
array_shift($a->{$var});
```

This function uses reference to the value and removes (and returns) value from the beginning of your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  class A
 {
   public  function fun()
   {       
      $this->arr[0] = "hello";
   }

   public $arr;
}


 $a = new A();
 $a->fun();

 // no need to take $var here 
 // you can directly access $arr property wihth object of class

 /*$var ="arr";*/

 // check the difference here  
 unset($a->arr[0]);  //unset "hello" value

 print_r($a);

?>
```

TRY THIS

Answer (score 0):

since $arr is a member of the class A and declared public, you can directly use

```
$a = new A();
$a->fun();
unset $a->arr[0];
```

But you will be surprised that for numeric indexed arrays, unset may bring problems.

suppose your array is like that;

```
$arr = ["zero","one","two","three","four"];
unset($arr[2]);       // now you removed "two"
echo $arr[3];         // echoes three
```

Now array is  ["zero","one", undefined ,"three","four"];

$arr[2] does not exist, it is undefined, and the rest is not reindexed...

for numeric indexed arrays using the method below is better:

```
$arr = ["zero","one","two","three","four"];
array_splice($arr,2,1);  // now you removed "two" and reindexed the array 
echo $arr[3];            // echoes four...
```

Now array is ["zero","one","three","four"];